# strip() and strip(string.whitespace) give different results despite documentation suggesting they should be the same

Tags: python, unicode, whitespace, strip

I have a Unicode string with some non-breaking spaces at the beginning and end.  I get different results when using `strip()` vs. `strip(string.whitespace)`.

```
>>> import string
>>> s5 = u'\xa0\xa0hello\xa0\xa0'
>>> print s5.strip()
hello
>>> print s5.strip(string.whitespace)
  hello
```

The documentation for `strip()` says, "If omitted or `None`, the `chars` argument defaults to removing whitespace."  The documentation for `string.whitespace` says, "A string containing all characters that are considered whitespace."

So if `string.whitespace` contains all characters that are considered whitespace, then why are the results different?  Does it have something to do with Unicode?

I am using Python 2.7.6

Comment: `string.whitespace` is `" \t\n\r\x0b\x0c"` on my Python 3.2.3. Clearly Unicode is out of the picture.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say that `string.whitespace` is used by `unicode.strip` to define what is and is not whitespace, however. I believe most of the `string` module is deprecated, having been folded into the `str` class itself.

Comment: @chepner apart from constants, Template, Formatter and maketrans - yup... pretty much all on the class now

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the documentation of the [`string.whitespace`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#string.whitespace):

> A string containing all **ASCII characters** that are considered
>   whitespace. This includes the characters space, tab, linefeed, return,
>   formfeed, and vertical tab.

It's the same under python3, where all non-ASCII constants where removed. (In python2 some constants could be influenced by `locale` settings).

Hence the difference in behaviour is quite obvious since `strip()` *does* remove any *unicode* whitespace, while `strip(string.whitespace)` removes only ASCII spaces. Your string clearly contains non-ASCII spaces.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting.  The documentation from Python 3.1 (the link you posted) does say "ASCII characters".  The documentation from Python 2.7 on [string.whitespace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.whitespace) does not specifically say "ASCII characters".  I wonder if it is different in Python 2.7, or if the documentation is just lacking those two words.

Comment: @Beccacodes As I said in python2 some of those "constants" actually depend on the locale settings. In python3 this is not true. Note that `locale` != unicode. In python3 they decided to get rid of this `locale` dependent behaviour and only kept the ASCII variants. I don't know why they didn't change the name to `ascii_whitespace`. Also note that `string.whitespace` in python2 is a *byte* string, which should already tell you that it *cannot* contain all unicode whitespace characters.

Comment: I have not worked with unicode much, so I am having a bit of trouble understanding. It _sounds_ like you are saying that in Python 2.7, string.whitespace _could_ contain some non-ASCII characters, based on locale settings.  But it sounds like the character u'\xa0' would still not be a possible candidate.  Why?

Comment: @Beccacodes `string.whitespace` is a byte string, this means it cannot contain a unicode "character" or "codepoint". At most it could contain a unicode character *encoded* in some encoding. For example `u'\xa0'.encode('utf-8')` *could* be found in `string.whitespace` using some locale settings. However, on my machine even changing the locale doesn't change `string.whitespace`.