# Removing Narrow 'No-Break Space' Unicode Characters (U+00A0) in python nlp

Tags: python-3.x, string, nlp, python-unicode, unicode-string

Non-breaking spaces are printed as whitespace, but handled internally as `\xa0`. How do I remove all these characters at once?

So far I've replaced it directly:

```
text = text.replace('\u202f','')  
text = text.replace('\u200d','') 
text = text.replace('\xa0','')
```

But each time I scrape the text sentences from external source, These characters are different. How do I remove it all at once?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression substitution instead.
If you want to replace all whitespace, you can just use:

```
import re

text = re.sub(r'\s', '', text)
```

This includes all unicode whitespace, as described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903317/is-there-a-python-constant-for-unicode-whitespace).
From that answer, you can see that (at the time of writing), the unicode constants recognized as whitespace (e.g. `\s`) in Python regular expressions are these:

```
0x0009
0x000A
0x000B
0x000C
0x000D
0x001C
0x001D
0x001E
0x001F
0x0020
0x0085
0x00A0
0x1680
0x2000
0x2001
0x2002
0x2003
0x2004
0x2005
0x2006
0x2007
0x2008
0x2009
0x200A
0x2028
0x2029
0x202F
0x205F
0x3000
```

This looks as if this will fit your needs.

Comment: Every new day while scraping, the unicode characters following usually \u202 are different. So, I want to remove all its occurences. How do i do that?

Comment: So you are saying they are not whitespace? What are they then? Have you tried the whitespace removal as in the answer?

Comment: I updated the answer to show what is recognized as whitespace in regular expressions.