# Preserve newlines in nestedExpr

Tags: python, newline, pyparsing

Is it possible for `nestedExpr` to preserve newlines?

Here is a simple example:

```
import pyparsing as pp

# Parse expressions like: \name{body}
name = pp.Word( pp.alphas )
body = pp.nestedExpr( '{', '}' )
expr = '\\' + name('name') + body('body')

# Example text to parse
txt = '''
This \works{fine}, but \it{
    does not
    preserve newlines
}
'''

# Show results
for e in expr.searchString(txt):
    print 'name: ' + e.name
    print 'body: ' + str(e.body) + '\n'
```

Output:

```
name: works
body: [['fine']]

name: it
body: [['does', 'not', 'preserve', 'newlines']]
```

As you can see, the body of the second expression (`\it{ ...`) is parsed despite the newlines in the body, but I would have expected the result to store each line in a separate subarray. This result makes it impossible to distinguish body contents with single vs. multiple lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't get to look at your answer until just a few minutes ago, and I had already come up with this approach:

```
body = pp.nestedExpr( '{', '}', content = (pp.LineEnd() | name.setWhitespaceChars(' ')))
```

Changing `body` to this definition gives these results:

```
name: works
body: [['fine']]

name: it
body: [['\n', 'does', 'not', '\n', 'preserve', 'newlines', '\n']]
```

EDIT:

Wait, if what you want are the separate lines, then perhaps this is more what you are looking for:

```
single_line = pp.OneOrMore(name.setWhitespaceChars(' ')).setParseAction(' '.join)
multi_line = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Optional(single_line) + pp.LineEnd().suppress())
body = pp.nestedExpr( '{', '}', content = multi_line | single_line )
```

Which gives:

```
name: works
body: [['fine']]

name: it
body: [['does not', 'preserve newlines']]
```

Comment: I don't think it gets better than an answer from the author of the package himself! :) Sorry if my suggestion was a bit clumsy, but can I just ask in this one; why do you use `name` in the definition of `body`? I admit it's not entirely clear from my question, but what I am really after are the _raw_ contents between the brackets, ideally untouched by any parsing rule or tokeniser, so I can parse them separately later on (possibly then with different parsing rules, depending on the contents of the parent).

Comment: To match *anything*, in place of `name` you'd probably use something like `pp.Word(pp.printables, excludeChars="{}")`. You may also have to fiddle with wrapping with `pp.originalTextFor` to get the raw string contents. Welcome to pyparsing!

Answer (score 0):

This extension (based on the code of `nestedExpr` version 2.1.10) behaves more closely to what I would expect a "nested expression" to return:

```
import string
from pyparsing import *

defaultWhitechars = string.whitespace
ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(defaultWhitechars)

def fencedExpr( opener="(", closer=")", content=None, ignoreExpr=None, stripchars=defaultWhitechars ):

    if content is None:
        if isinstance(opener,basestring) and isinstance(closer,basestring):
            if len(opener) == 1 and len(closer)==1:
                if ignoreExpr is not None:
                    content = Combine(OneOrMore( ~ignoreExpr + CharsNotIn(opener+closer,exact=1)))
                else:
                    content = empty.copy() + CharsNotIn(opener+closer)
            else:
                if ignoreExpr is not None:
                    content = OneOrMore( ~ignoreExpr + ~Literal(opener) + ~Literal(closer))
                else:
                    content = OneOrMore( ~Literal(opener) + ~Literal(closer) )
        else:
            raise ValueError("opening and closing arguments must be strings if no content expression is given")

    if stripchars is not None:
        content.setParseAction(lambda t:t[0].strip(stripchars))

    ret = Forward()
    if ignoreExpr is not None:
        ret <<= Group( Suppress(opener) + ZeroOrMore( ignoreExpr | ret | content ) + Suppress(closer) )
    else:
        ret <<= Group( Suppress(opener) + ZeroOrMore( ret | content )  + Suppress(closer) )
    ret.setName('nested %s%s expression' % (opener,closer))
    return ret
```

IMHO it fixes a few things:

1. The original implementation uses `ParserElement.DEFAULT_WHITE_CHARS` in the default `content`, which appears to be out of laziness; it is only used five times outside the `ParserElement` class itself, four of which in the function `nestedExpr` (the other usage is in `LineEnd`, and it manually removes `\n`). It would be easy enough to add a named argument to `nestedExpr` instead, although to be fair we can also use [`ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars`](http://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.ParserElement-class.html#setDefaultWhitespaceChars) to achieve the same thing.
2. The second issue is that by default, whitespace chars are ignored in the `content` expression itself, with the additional parse action `lambda t:t[0].strip()`, where strip is called without input, meaning that it [removes all unicode whitespace characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22231264/472610). I personally think it makes more sense not to ignore any whitespace within the content, but to strip them selectively in the result instead. For that reason, I removed the tokens with `CharsNotIn` in the original implementation, and introduced the argument `stripchars` which defaults to `string.whitespace`.

Happy to take any constructive criticism on this of course.

Comment: Thanks for making the effort to work up some working patch code - I usually get suggestions on changes *I* should make to pyparsing, but only seldom get concrete code patches/implementations. Your interpretation of `nestedExpr` is a little different from mine, I think, and I tried to accommodate different nesting rules by supporting the `content` argument, the default being 0 or more whitespace-delimited words. I may need to remove that auto-strip() parse action though if a `content` expression is given, and let the caller set necessary strip or join or whatever parse actions on the given arg.